# Image from bytearray not complete in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsp, data-uri

Java6, Struts2.2.3.1 - I'm converting a byte array to an image(jpg). Please see the link below, if you open this in IE the image is not complete, whereas it opens fine in Firefox or Chrome

http://jsbin.com/aheliy/2

**Java**
I encode the bytearray and convert to String using [MiGBase64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/migbase64/) - where this.bean.imageByteArrayString refers to the form bean

```
this.bean.setImageByteArrayString(new Base64().encodeToString(imageInByteArr, false));
```

**JSP**

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<c:out value='${bean.imageByteArrayString}'/>" />
```

Not sure why this is not working in IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 has a 32KB limit on the data URI scheme. See also [the wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

I suggest to generate a normal URL instead and have a servlet to serve the image, or if the image is actually already located on the disk file system of the webserver, to create another webapp context so that you can just reference it directly by URL.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also aware of this size limit, but when I checked the size of the partial image in IE that's nearly 750kb. So got a bit confused. I want to retrieve image from bytearray in the bean which also has other attributes like id, desc etc. and avoid additional server hit for image retrieval. I'm getting this image array from a webservice and don't have it in file system.

Comment: I scrapped my original plan of assigning byte array in the img tag, since I couldn't get it correct in IE8. Now using a struts action class to render the image by outputting bytes to the output stream.